# Difference between "snoop around" and "stick one's nose in other people's affairs"

Tags: idioms

is there any difference between "snoop around" and "stick one's nose in other people's affairs" as opposite to "mind your own business"? Is it possible to say politely "I would like not to snoop around" to indicate that I'm not going to insist on my participation = make smb's life hard this way?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's look at these idioms:

(The idiom) 'snoop around' action is intentionally done in order to find something secret or something about someone's personal life. The [Free Dictionary describes it.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/snoop+around)

On the other hand, *mind your own business* is used when you don't want someone to *ask or interfere* about or in your personal life/affair. [EnglishClub](http://www.englishclub.com/ref/esl/Idioms/M/Mind_your_own_business__90.htm) describes this with examples.

*Stick one's nose in other people's affair* means *to interject one's self into another person's affairs. Implies that the interjection is unwanted* -- [OnlineSlangDictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/stick-%28one%27s%29-nose-in-other-people%27s-business). As a side note, I have come more across *[poke someone's nose into....](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/poke+nose+into)* as an alternative to this idiom.

Now your question:

The difference is *snoop around* is often carried out secretly generally to spy on someone or know the truth. If you [*snoop* on a person,](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/snoop%20around) probably you are a detective and trying to find out the truths in that *someone's* life. A [snooper](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SNOOPER) is someone who makes uninvited inquiries into the private affairs of others. On the other hand, if you *stick your nose* in my life, you are trying to *interfere* in my life/personal affair. You are unnecessarily *involving* yourself in my matter. This **could be** someone's *nature* but the former one is not.

I'll try with examples:

> I'm having doubts. I'll pay you for this. Just **snoop around** on my wife and find out who she's meeting every day.
>
> Sure, you're good friends my wife. But let her make decisions on her own. Why do you **stick your nose into** her professional life? She's more capable enough to make a decision without your help.

Comment: I agree that _snooping around_ tends to be more clandestine, while _sticking your nose in someone else's affairs_ tends to be more open. There is some overlap between the two, but I wouldn't call them interchangeable.

Comment: @J.R for your edit - Cannot I say, "I have a doubt" if the doubt is **only** about meeting someone out of my knowledge? No *doubts?*

Comment: If you're feeling suspicious about something, that's generally expressed in the plural with _doubts_. I'll leave it that that here, but really, the question in your comment here probably deserves to be its own question on ELL. It's a good one. (If you don't ask it later today, I might even ask it myself.)

Comment: @J.R. In India, it's quite clear. If I have a doubt, I have *a doubt* and if there are several things ruining my mind, I have *doubts.* In fact, then we say *I have many doubts!*

Comment: Yes, but the tricky part is trying to quantify how many doubts you are having. Your sample sentence makes it sounds like the speaker suspects his wife may be in an adulterous relationship. If that were my wife, it would be hard to say that I have one and only one doubt about the situation; that's why I think the sample sentence is improved by using the plural.